# List.AddRange Performance of Adding Array vs List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, ienumerable

When using `List.AddRange()`, is there any difference in performance between adding a `List` or `Array`.

```
MyList.AddRange(MyArrayof1000ComplexElements);
```

VS

```
MyList.AddRange(MyListof1000ComplexElements);
```

or is there no difference?

Comment: Why don't you measure it ? and use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster_ **then race your horses**.

Comment: But it's still fun to guess before the race :-).

Comment: I was hoping I can get an answer from someone who's already done the homework. I know I can test this myself. That's why I posted it on SO in the first place.

Comment: @SonerGönül This needs to be printed everywhere

Comment: Also, it's not about who's faster. I would like to know the underlining differences. Performance is just as important as speed.

Comment: Questions like this seem to pop-up more and more lately. You probably spent more time asking this question and responding to comments that it would have taken you to test this yourself.

Comment: there should be no diffrence or at least an array could be minium faster than list, but i think that is not measurable. A List is a wrapper around an array, build for a more friendly user interface

Comment: I would guess that this in any event would be a micro optimization if one turns out to be faster for whatever reason . Probably not worth making api decisions based on the potential difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an array and a list both implement `ICollection<T>`, it uses the same code.
It resolves to a call to Array.Copy(...)

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#e569d850a66a1771#references

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `List<T>` and `T[]` - `AddRange` uses the same handling for anything implementing `ICollection<T>`, which both of those do.

Answer (score 1):

Both Array and List implement the `ICollection<T>` interface. Therefore, the implementation of `List.AddRange` that is used will be identical and will offer the same performance.

In the future, you can either test something like this yourself with a simple program using the `Stopwatch` class for timing or download a tool like JetBrain's dotPeek to inspect the framework code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

This is a more interesting question than some of the comments might suggest.

As it happens, for this specific list/array implementation the answer is: no difference. Both rely on the same collection interface.

But it doesn't have to be that way. If a list is implemented as a doubly-linked list (which it is in many other cases) then appending one list to another is O(1) while appending an array to a list is O(n).

And I would not start by benchmarking to resolve this question. Benchmarking is time-consuming to do well and can easily produce results susceptible to misinterpretation. In this case a careful study of the implementation and the underlying source code (easily available through a .NET disassembler) will answer the question faster. Then benchmark to confirm, if it matters enough.

---

Please note that the specific O(1) optimisation that applies here is only available if `MyListof1000ComplexElements` too is a List. If it some kind of enumerator or linked list then the performance will be O(n).

---

In response to those who have criticised this answer, please note that it has been written with the intention of highlighting that the other answers given are based on a specific interpretation of the question. They fail to point out how narrowly they have interpreted the question and how narrowly their answers apply. Another reader might easily miss the fact that this answer only applies to this specific circumstance if they don't say so. My aim is simply to point out that in many other closely related situations, this is an O(n) operation rather than O(1).

Comment: There is a linked list implementation, and it's called `LinkedList`.  `List` is, by the definition provided for it, an array backed list, and should be treated as such.  That is not an implementation detail; it is an explicit part of the contract of the type.

Comment: I would fully agree with this answer if this was a generic programming question. In the world of .NET however, `List<T>` and `T[]` have very specific implementations that will never change due to backward compatibility (precedent in both .NET and other languages is that if such a change is required, a new differently-named class is introduced).

Comment: @decPL It's more than even that.  The fact that `List` is an array based list *is explicitly defined in the documentation as the implementation of that data structure*.  It's not a private implementation detail that everyone simply relies on.  It's *publicly defined behavior*.  It would not simply be a bad idea to change the implementation to a linked list, but *it would violated it's own public contract* to do so.

Comment: So your advice is to study the code, make conclusions then back those up with benchmarks - rather than jump straight to the benchmark and maybe try to reason the results? Seems odd to me, especially given "Benchmarking is time-consuming to do well and can easily produce results susceptible to misinterpretation".

Comment: @DanielKelley: Sorry, don't understand. My advice is the scientific method: analyse the problem and (if necessary) construct experiments to test specific hypotheses, then match results to theory. In this case a careful study of the code would avoid any need for benchmarks.

Comment: @david.pfx We will have to agree to disagree on this. Your suggestion to me is like studying an athletes physical and mental strength to figure out who is the fastest over 100m rather than just lining them up and getting them to race.